# Configure AWS instance to use IPv6

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv6, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create an instance which will have an IPv6 address and I follow this tutorial:
[Getting Started with IPv6 for Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/get-started-ipv6.html)

- My instance will start and get an IPv6 address.
- I can also ssh into it but I can't download anything. For example apt-get install will not run and also ping google.com will not receive any packages.
- Security group will allow all traffic

However when I assign an Elastic IP address to the instance the above commands will run fine.
Is there any way to have an AWS instance with only an IPv6 address?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you configure it. Make sure you have IPv6 CIDR's assigned to your instance VPC.

**IPv6 EC2 Documentation:**

More detailed documentation on IPv6 EC2 documentations is available here,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/get-started-ipv6.html

[image: ipv6 cidr]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you everything seems to be working. I didn't know that not all websites accept IPv6

Comment: Your machine has IPv4 and IPv6. When a machine is IPv6 it queries for AAAA dns query and connects using ipv6 else if it fallback to ipv4. Not sure where you have the issue.

Comment: There is no issue. I didn't know I had to run 'ping6 google.com' because my I was using an IPv6. Also apt-get update doesn't work well with IPv6 so I will have to investigate it.